# jquery form validation on hidden subcategory field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I need jquery validation on a form which has title, category, subcategory and message fields. I have been able to get validation on everything except the subcategory. For some reason i just can't get it to work. I hope some one here can help me out.

The validation code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var adForm = jQuery("#Add_post_form"); 
    var cc_title = jQuery("#title");   
    var cc_desc = jQuery("#cc_desc");
    var cc_desc_error = jQuery(".desc_error");
    var cat = jQuery("#cat");
    var cat_error = jQuery(".category_error");
    function validate_title(){
        if(cc_title.val() == ''){
            cc_title.addClass("error");
            cc_title.attr("placeholder", "<?php echo ENTER_TITLE; ?>");
            cc_title.css('border', 'solid 1px red');
            cc_title.css('background-color', '#ffece8');
            return false;
        }else{
            cc_title.removeClass("error");   
            cc_title.css('border', 'none');
            cc_title.css('background-color', '');
            return true;
        }
    }
    cc_title.blur(validate_title);
    cc_title.keyup(validate_title);
    function validate_desc(){
        if(cc_desc.val() == ""){
            cc_desc.addClass("error");
            cc_desc.css('border', 'solid 1px red');
            cc_desc_error.addClass("error");
            cc_desc_error.text("<?php echo ENTER_DES; ?>");
            return false;
        }else{
            cc_desc.removeClass("error");
            cc_desc_error.removeClass("error");
            cc_desc_error.text("");
            cc_desc.css('border', 'none');
            return true;
        }
    }
    cc_desc.blur(validate_desc);
    cc_desc.keyup(validate_desc);
    function validate_category(){
        if(cat.val() == '-1'){
            cat.addClass("error");
            cat.css('border', 'solid 1px red');
            cat_error.addClass("error");
            cat_error.text("<?php echo ENTER_CAT; ?>");
            return false;
        }else{
            cat.removeClass("error");
            cat_error.removeClass("error");
            cat_error.text("");
            cat.css('border', 'none');
            return true;
        }
    }
    cat.blur(validate_category);
    cat.keyup(validate_category);

    adForm.submit(function()
    {
        if(validate_title() & validate_desc() & validate_category())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

My form js:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function displaychk_frm(){
        dom = document.forms['add_post_form'];
        chk = dom.elements['category[]'];
        len = dom.elements['category[]'].length;

        if(document.getElementById('selectall').checked == true) { 
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
                chk[i].checked = true ;
        } else { 
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
                chk[i].checked = false ;
        }
    }
</script>
```

The form HTLM:

```
<form name="add_post_form" id="Add_post_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!--Start Step1-->
<div class="step1">
    <div class="label">
        <label><?php echo AD_TTLE; ?></label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" name="cc_title" maxlength="40" id="title"/>
    </div>   
    <div class="label">
        <label><?php echo SLT_CAT; ?></label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="ad-categories">                      
            <div id="catlvl0">
                <?php
                wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=' . __('Selecteer categorie', 'appthemes') . '&class=dropdownlist&orderby=name&order=ASC&hide_empty=0&hierarchical=1&taxonomy=' . CUSTOM_CAT_TYPE . '&depth=1');
                ?>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div id="ad-categories-footer">               
            <div id="chosenCategory"><input id="cat" name="cc_category" type="hidden" value="-1" />

</div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="label">
        <label for="cc_desc"><?php echo DESC; ?></label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <textarea name="cc_description" id="cc_desc"></textarea>           
                </div>                             
</div>
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="step1" value="NEXT"/>
```

Since i am validating by ID and both the category and subcategory have the same ID (cat) i would assume the validation should work on both fields but it does not.

The subcategory dropdown field is hidden until the user chooses a category first. Maybe that has something to do with it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the same id on different elements.

From the JQuery docs:

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one element using the same ID is invalid.

https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing with elements with Jquery then you need to have ID or Class or tagName. If two elements have same id then you can do something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($("select:eq( 0 )").find("option:eq(0)").html());
  alert($("select:eq( 1 )").find("option:eq(0)").html());

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="cat">
  <option>Item1
    <option>
</select>


<select id="cat">
  <option>SubItem1
    <option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried your suggestion but it does not work. In fact when i tried it nothing got validated anymore.

Comment: how many selects you have in ur form? And what is the index of your selects that u are trying to validate(category and sub-category)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the index. The main / parent category has 3 options. Each subcategory / child has several options. It does not go deeper. The default value is -1, i am validating on the value not being -1.